# Is it possible to get the definition of a Stored Procedure using the name (without having to look in the object explorer)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm working on a database that has an huge number of stored procedures. The frustrating part is that the naming convention is not consistent. I spent half of my time looking for them in the **object explorer**.

I'd like to know whether there's a way to get the **definition of a SPROC** just by knowing the name? Something like:

```
SELECT commande(name_of_SPROC) --> Display the definition of the SPROC
```

Just anything that can help me get the definition of a SPROC without having to search in the Object explorer of the **SQL Server Management Studio**.

Thanks for helping

Comment: There is a free tool I use for searching databases, it's called [Sql Search](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-search/). The benefit of this is that a double click on the search results gets the object focused in the object explorer.

Comment: You can filter object explorer if you need to, filtering on say procedures containing a certain string. Right click on Stored Procedures Folder and select Filter, type in your criteria

Comment: Interesting! I didn't know you could even filter object by names.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, there are many ways:

**1. Using system SP: sp_helptext:**

```
sp_helptext 'your_sp_name'
```

**2. Using INFORMATION_SCHEMA views:**

```
select ROUTINE_DEFINITION, * 
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES 
where ROUTINE_NAME = 'your_sp_name';
```

**3. Using sys.sql_modules view:**

```
select definition, *
from sys.sql_modules 
where object_name(object_id) = 'your_sp_name'
```

**4. Using sys.syscomments view:**

```
select text, * 
from sys.syscomments 
where object_name(id) = 'your_sp_name'
```

The best one to use is the **sp_helptext**, its also very handy and fast.
Other option I like is **sql_modules** sys view.
Do not use **syscomments** sys view as it splits bigger SPs into multiple rows, [check here](https://sqlwithmanoj.com/2012/08/01/search-a-string-in-stored-procedure-view-function-or-other-database-object-definitions/).

Comment: `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES.ROUTINE_DEFINITION` returns first 4,000 characters. Routines longer than that are truncated. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188757.aspx

Comment: Yes, this one and sys.syscomments have this limitation, and that's why I've mentioned for the later one, and one should use sys.sql_modules view instead to get the full SP body.

Comment: Thank you so much. I feel already better as I don't have to search anymore in the pile.

Answer (score 3):

You can use something like,

```
    sp_helptext '<sprocname>'
```

Answer (score 3):

System procedure `sp_helpText` can be used to return stored procedure code.